# Can't dispatch DDM chunk 46454154: no handler defined - Eclipse - Android SDK

Tags: android, eclipse, runtime-error

I'm working on a Windows 7, 64 bit machine, and just downloaded and installed the Android SDK and am using Eclipse with Android plugin.

I was just going through the "Hello Android" guide here:
[Hello, Android](http://developer.android.com/guide/tutorials/hello-world.html)

I also did the suggestions on this page: [Droid FAQ](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/faq/troubleshooting.html#eclipse)

Before following the FAQ, the program would compile and run but wouldn't register with the emulator. No code changes, and now I get the following.

When I try to run the emulator, I get the following message:

```
[2010-03-05 20:48:41 - HelloAndroid]ActivityManager: Can't dispatch DDM chunk 46454154: no handler defined
[2010-03-05 20:48:41 - HelloAndroid]ActivityManager: Can't dispatch DDM chunk 4d505251: no handler defined
[2010-03-05 20:48:42 - HelloAndroid]ActivityManager: Starting: Intent { comp={domain.example.helloandroid/domain.example.helloandroid.HelloAndroid} }
[2010-03-05 20:48:42 - HelloAndroid]ActivityManager: Warning: Activity not started, its current task has been brought to the front
```

Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: The "can't dispatch DDM chunk" message is irrelevant, and has been removed from an upcoming release of Android.

Comment: i am also facing the same error for the I am calling a socket connection to a port 5090 seems wiered that android system doesnt give useful messages

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by it wouldn't register with the emulator, but I get the exact same error messages every time I run a program. However, it hasn't stopped my programs from compiling and running on both my emulator and actual phone.

(Edit: I should add that I'm compiling using Eclipse with both Android v1.5 and 2.1 installled, and those messages appear in LogCat when I run programs on my v1.5 emulator. Haven't checked with the v2.1)

As for the second two lines in the error message, particularly the Activity not started, that's simply because you didn't change the code before trying to install it again. A simple fix for that is to remove a character (anything really) and then put it back in. That forces it to 'rebuild the workspace' when you save, which in turn forces it to reinstall on the emulator.

Comment: The emulator wasn't seeing my application at run-time. Anyways, you were right, it actually was compiling. It was starting behind my IDE and I didn't even see it. DOH. Actually restarting Eclipse got rid of the "Can't dispatch" messages.

Comment: Oh yea, thanks for the heads up on the second 2 lines as well. That cleared up the last of the confusion for me!! Ready to dive in now ;)