# Android app works on emulator but not on phone ("Can't dispatch DDM chunk XXXX: no handler defined")

Tags: java, xml, android, mobile, android-emulator

I made a very simple application to start playing around with Android development.

It works fine on the emulator, but it gives me the following error when I try to install it on my HTC Hero (v1.5):

> Sorry! The application Simple Dial (process com.foo.simpledial) has
>   stopped unexpectedly.  Please try again. (Force Close button)

and on in the **Eclipse console**, I get the following message:

```
[2010-06-14 23:10:52 - Simple Dial] Uploading Simple Dial.apk onto device 'HT9BSHF00222'
[2010-06-14 23:10:53 - Simple Dial] Installing Simple Dial.apk...
[2010-06-14 23:10:56 - Simple Dial] Success!
[2010-06-14 23:10:56 - Simple Dial] Starting activity com.alanvaghti.simpledial.DialActivity on device 

[2010-06-14 23:10:57 - Simple Dial] ActivityManager: Can't dispatch DDM chunk 46454154: no handler defined
[2010-06-14 23:10:57 - Simple Dial] ActivityManager: Can't dispatch DDM chunk 4d505251: no handler defined

[2010-06-14 23:10:57 - Simple Dial] ActivityManager: Starting: Intent { action=android.intent.action.MAIN categories={android.intent.category.LAUNCHER} comp={com.alanvaghti.simpledial/com.alanvaghti.simpledial.DialActivity} }
```

I did put `android:debuggable="true"` inside the application tag on the manifest.xml

Any ideas on what is going on??  Thanks in advance!

Comment: Actually, the app does not work in the 1.5 emulator, but does in the 2.2 emulator... hmmmm

Comment: Maybe this can help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2391654/cant-dispatch-ddm-chunk-46454154-no-handler-defined-eclipse-android-sdk

Comment: The "Can't dispatch DDM chunk" warning can be ignored.  There should be more in the log than what you have above after a "force close", e.g. some sort of crash.

Comment: try posting code off app; since it works for 2.2 but not for 1.5 perhaps you are using some api from above 1.5 version.

Comment: (note to editor) @KrupaPatel, please, use the *Summary* field to describe your edit. **Do not** paste the post content there!

Answer (score 0):

Have the uses-sdk in your manifest?

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="4" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I also see the same problem in my phone, but in emulator it works fine. Try debugging the app in the phone (USB debug), not in emulator. In my case, an "out of bound exception" in an array caused the crash in phone. To debug in the phone, you need to install "google usb driver".
Regards
   Charly

Answer (score 0):

This is the problem that many of us would be facing and this problem may not be applicable only to testing the app but also to the app that you install on your device.
Android has 4 Layouts (most of us know)

Layout
Layout-small
Layout-large
Layout-xlarge

The issue with me was that I made the change in the XML file in the layout-small folder which supports 2.7 inches. 
I ran the Emulator which was again for 2.7 inches and worked absolutely fine.
Now when I exported the signed application and tested in the device, it fails. The reason was that I did not make the necessary changes in the Layout folder.
My device was expecting some fields for the calculation that was in the main.xml file but not in the version installed.
So couple of things you should do.
1) When testing the application, do create only 1 folder (layout with all the xml files) and that way you will be able to test the FUNCTIONALITY of your app on all devices.
2) if you have created all the Layout folders and then make change in any XML file, do make sure that the change(s) is(are) cascaded to all folders.

Happy development...